# How to manage programmatically the access of a content node type?

Tags: 7, nodes, users

From a custom module, I created a new type of content type via the drupal api (using the hook node_info). Thanks that, I can create node of this content type.

I would like allow access to nodes of this content type only for his author. And I want the author have only access to the view page of the node (edit page denied). How can I do that?

In Short:
In my custom module, how allow only access to the view node page only the author of the node? 
The author can only access to the view page of a node created by the author. And, edits pages aren't be accessible for all non-admin users.

Comment: This is definitely a dup.  Not sure what the best target is, though.

Answer (score 1):

We need to set permission for doing this. Permission can be done specific to a Role not to a User. Please use below codes. Please update your role name instead of 'New Role' and machine name of your content_type instead of 'your_content_type'.

```
$role_name = "New Role";
$role_permissions = array(
  'create your_content_type content',
  );

$role = user_role_load_by_name($role_name);
user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $role_permissions);
```